# android move button

Tags: android, view, move

I want create activity, and put buttons on any position of screen.

But I can't figure out how to do that.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <Button android:text="start" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In this case button apears in the bottom of screen. But I want button to be a little higher.But I can't.
So is there any method to put buttons on the screen using coordinates or anything else?

Comment: what kind of layout exactly you are trying to design?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` to the button.
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button android:text="start" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a higher value? `android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"`

Comment: I just tested in eclipse and you can adjust the distance from the bottom by changing that value.

Comment: when we use layout_marginLeft atribute, its specify an extra space in the left side of view.
so how I understand, we can't put another view keft for that view.
am I right?
so how to put several views side by side, in the middle of screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try out [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

**Edit:** From the site:

> FrameLayout is the simplest type of layout object. It's basically a
>   blank space on your screen that you can later fill with a single
>   object — for example, a picture that you'll swap in and out. All child
>   elements of the FrameLayout are pinned to the top left corner of the
>   screen; you cannot specify a different location for a child view.
>   Subsequent child views will simply be drawn over previous ones,
>   partially or totally obscuring them (unless the newer object is
>   transparent).

Comment: Next time please add a small description for your links so we aren't forced to visit the site to know if your answer is solid. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Use relative layout and within that linear layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
.....
<LinearLayout>
.....
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And use margin attribute.

```
android:layout_marginTop
android:layout_marginRIght
android:layout_marginBottom
android:layout_marginLeft
```

In your case..

```
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
```

you can provide the value as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
android:layout_marginTop= ""
```